# Android: Working with AppWidget and their allowed operations

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I'm here to ask you an help to my doubts on AppWidget.
At the moment I'm trying to build an AppWidget that visualizes a timetable;
I have build a layout that contains columns for days of week made of:
a FrameLayout that contains a LinearLayout(for a background) and a RelativeLayout in which I want to put user appointments.
About appointments I want to build TextView that can be different in dimension, color, and position in the RelativeLayout...

is there anyone who knows how to this?

I have seen that RemoteViews are very limited in available actions but at the same time I have found some AppWidgets those do this feature..

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate widgets to a certain extend (e.g. setting a completely different widget layout when updating it), but yes, `RemoteViews` are somewhat limited. Since the first part of your question is vague, I can only give this answer here. But which `Views` you can use and what operations are available on `RemoteView`s is pretty well documented.

What you might have seen, and is quite common, is something that looks like a widget but is in reality a launcher feature. For example the HTC sense widgets. These can have different sizes for one single widget entry from the menu, listviews and some other things. Thats because they are using the sense launcher in an undocumentated way that is not useable by external devs. Often you can find out if the widget in question is a real widget by placing it using a different launcher (e.g. the android stock launcher). This can't be done with these 'special' widgets, they will show an error.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the answer, maybe I can be more precise if I show you an image of what I need to do...

https://www.gstatic.com/android/market/com.evobile.app.ltt/ss-480-6-3

If you see the appointments are resizable, with different colour and positioned in different places... I'm tryng to do it with a RelativeLayout over a LinearLayout in a FrameLayout, but the added views are added and visualized at the top of the AppWidget layout..

Comment: That should be a bit complicated *(you have to generate at least the appointment overlay in code in a dynamic way)*, but possible afterall. The only part that might be impossible is the resizable appointments. If you want to resize the appointments inside the widget, I think thats not possible. What you can do is write an activity that's used to edit the data and update the widget with a new layout after something changed.

Comment: Mmm I'm not the only one that thinks this is an impossible thing...
I have passed all this afternoon trying to find a way and the only "stupid" but "lovable" way to this it's:
- activity with the timetable layout
- image obtained by the activity
- widget with the resized image that is updated every time an orary changes